# Asynchronous crawling F#

Tags: f#, web-crawler

When crawling on webpages I need to be careful as to not make too many requests to the same domain, for example I want to put 1 s between requests. From what I understand it is the time between requests that is important. So to speed things up I want to use async workflows in F#, the idea being make your requests with 1 sec interval but avoid blocking things while waiting for request response.

```
let getHtmlPrimitiveAsyncTimer (uri : System.Uri) (timer:int) =
    async{

            let req =  (WebRequest.Create(uri)) :?> HttpWebRequest
            req.UserAgent<-"Mozilla"
            try 

                Thread.Sleep(timer)
                let! resp =    (req.AsyncGetResponse())
                Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri+" got response")
                use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
                use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
                let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
                return html
            with 
            | _ as ex -> return "Bad Link"
                 }
```

Then I do something like:

```
let uri1 = System.Uri "http://rue89.com"
let timer = 1000
let jobs = [|for i in 1..10 -> getHtmlPrimitiveAsyncTimer uri1 timer|]

jobs
|> Array.mapi(fun i job -> Console.WriteLine("Starting job "+string i)
                               Async.StartAsTask(job).Result)
```

Is this alright ? I am very unsure about 2 things:
-Does the Thread.Sleep thing work for delaying the request ?
-Is using StartTask a problem ?

I am a beginner (as you may have noticed) in F# (coding in general actually ), and everything envolving Threads scares me :)

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to do is
 - create 10 jobs, numbered 'n', each starting 'n' seconds from now
 - run those all in parallel

Approximately like

```
let makeAsync uri n = async {
    // create the request
    do! Async.Sleep(n * 1000)
    // AsyncGetResponse etc
    }

let a = [| for i in 1..10 -> makeAsync uri i |]
let results = a |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Note that of course they all won't start exactly now, if e.g. you have a 4-core machine, 4 will start running very soon, but then quickly execute up to the Async.Sleep, at which point the next 4 will run up until their sleeps, and so forth.  And then in one second the first async wakes up and posts a request, and another second later the 2nd async wakes up, ... so this should work.  The 1s is only approximate, since they're starting their timers each a very tiny bit staggered from one another... you may want to buffer it a little, e.g. 1100 ms or something if the cut-off you need is really exactly a second (network latencies and whatnot still leave a bit of this outside the possible control of your program probably).

`Thread.Sleep` is suboptimal, it will work ok for a small number of requests, but you're burning a thread, and threads are expensive and it won't scale to a large number.

You don't need `StartAsTask` unless you want to interoperate with .NET Tasks or later do a blocking rendezvous with the result via `.Result`.  If you just want these to all run and then block to collect all the results in an array, `Async.Parallel` will do that fork-join parallelism for you just fine.  If they're just going to print results, you can fire-and-forget via `Async.Start` which will drop the results on the floor.

(An alternative strategy is to use an agent as a throttle.  Post all the http requests to a single agent, where the agent is logically single-threaded and sits in a loop, doing `Async.Sleep` for 1s, and then handling the next request.  That's a nice way to make a general-purpose throttle... may be blog-worthy for me, come to think of it.)

Comment: Hehe! Very very nice, thank you. F# is truly amazing, i love the "Async.Parallel" will do that for you :) , for beginners like me it lets you worry about getting the code right.
Thank you !

Comment: Progress has been made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023153/asynchronous-webcrawling-f-something-wrong

Comment: Actually Brian, I am not sure this solution works for a large number of uri's, or does it ?

Comment: See my response there; the problem there is different than the problem here, since here you know all the uris a priori and kick off everything at once, whereas there you discover new uris during the program run.

Comment: Yes thank you saw it, working on it :) . 
For this post,it is no problem to launch |>Asyn.Parallel|>Asyn.RunSynchronously on a very large seq of Async elements ?

Comment: Right; I think this would be fine for tens of thousands of elements (though I haven't actually tried it); my hunch is the first limit would be the array of results (e.g. if you save the html-string of the pages in the results array, ensure you don't use up all the process memory storing all those big strings).